# Refreshing LINQ query on ComboBox Selection Changed

Tags: c#, linq, datagrid, combobox

I want to be able enumerate the query again once the selection has changed in the combo box. It is currently working but there must be a better way to this.

```
var cmbBox = (from c in db.Addresses
                      select c.City).Distinct();

        cmbQ2.ItemsSource = cmbBox;

        #endregion
    }

    private void cmbQ2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var q2 = from c in db.Customers
                 join ca in db.CustomerAddresses on c.CustomerID equals ca.CustomerID
                 join a in db.Addresses on ca.AddressID equals a.AddressID
                 where a.City == (string)cmbQ2.SelectedValue
                 select new { Name = c.FirstName, City = a.City };

        lbxQ2.ItemsSource = q2;
    }
```

[image: Using the combo box at the bottom of the window]

Comment: yeah but whats wrong with your current implementation? why do you want to change it if its working?

Comment: @Oluwafemi I would prefer if the selection changed event would simply call the query and leave the implementation to the background (left in the MainWindow).

Comment: So basicly you want to separate the query into a method which you will call from the event handler?

Comment: @Sami thats exactly what I'd like to do! I was running into access issues though. I've been working with C# not even a year now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a more fluent syntax... you could use this:

```
string selectedCity = (string)cmbQ2.SelectedValue;
var query = db.Addresses.Where(address => address.City == selectedCity)
                        .SelectMany(address => address.CustomerAddresses)
                        .Select(customerAddress => new 
                        {
                            Name = customerAddress.Customer.FirstName,
                            City = customerAddress.Address.City
                        });
```

The class `CustomerAddress` will need to have a navigation property referencing the `Customer` class and a navigation property to `Address`, you'll also need a collection of `CustomerAddress` as a navigation property on `Address`, e.g. `ICollection<CustomerAddress>`.

In addition to that, I would migrate all of that code into a separate project. Where ever your user interacts with your site, that layer is a presentation layer concern, so whether your app is developed using WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET, that project should only deal with issues concerning the user experience, presentation of the data it exposes and validation concerning input values, error messages etc.

The data access logic, the logic you've written above should be in a separate one... which your presentation layer can request content from.

I would highly recommend you begin to look into `N-Tier architecture` for structuring applications correctly.

I would also recommend you look into using `Entity Framework`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to move your data access logic in a separate file/class? If that's the case, you could make use of the Repository pattern instead of using plain old link queries.

Here is an example using EntityFramework: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207820/The-Repository-Pattern-with-EF-code-first-Dependen

Comment: You sure this is want he wants cos I smell some down votes.